# Should related objects be grouped in one table, or multiple?

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, database-design

This is mostly a database related question, but I'm using VB.net and sqlite.

So I have a group of Widgets, they all have a certain group of properties.  Among them is a "Type" property.

Depending on the Type property there are a series of additional type-dependent properties.  I'm wondering if it's normally a good idea to group these into a single table (and then likely a single class) with a lot of null values or should they be organized in the database in multiple tables (with derived classes), or something else?

Example:

- Widget 1: Small, Blue, Type A, 20 Pounds, Shiny
- Widget 2: Small, Red, Type B, Transparent
- Widget 3: Big, Yellow, Type C, 6 feet, 5 feet, 1 foot

Should they be organized in a table like this, with a lot of nulls:

- Widgits

  - ID, Size, Color, Type, Weight, isShiny, Transparency, width, length, height

Or like this:

- Widgits

  - ID, Size, Color, Type
- Widgits_A

  - ID, Weight, isShiny
- Widgits_B

  - ID, Transparency
- Widgits_C

  - ID, Width, Length, Height

Probably thousands of Widgets in the end, of possibly 20 types.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically, how many widgets do you foresee to handle?

Comment: Was just editing that in.  Thousands, in around 20 types.  Each type with 1-10 of their own unique properties.

Comment: Without knowing the exact nature of these 20 types I will suggest a separate table for each type. The SQLite language has the  CREATE VIEW statement and, eventually, you will be able to rejoin the information in meaningful ways.

Answer (score 1):

In the OOP world, what you have implemented in terms of a "Type" property would normally be implemented via inheritance.

Inheritance can be modeled in a database with a parent table (with one record per widget, regardless of type, storing only the fields of the base widget class), and a child table for each widget subtype.

This can make things easier for operations on all widgets (rather than doing a UNION of unrelated widget tables).

However, it can also make things more difficult.  For example, to just get all of the fields for one widget, you need to join the record from the parent table with the record from the appropriate child table.

Here's another post on this subject: [Table "Inheritance" in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/529256/21727)

Comment: I actually started with inherited objects in my OO application, when it came to storing this information long-term it lead me to the problem that I couldn't do that easily without a single table with a huge number of null-filled columns or a lot of tables.

Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is [object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), but you are running into the [object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch).
(Also read [Object-Relational Mapping is the Vietnam of Computer Science](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/06/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science.html).)

There is no easy solution.

What you could do is to list *all* operations your program will be doing on the widgets table(s), analyze how they would work with both organizations, and then choose the one that you estimate is easier to use and maintain overall.

Comment: "There is no easy solution."  This makes me feel better in a way.  I have been thinking that for a few days.  Glad to know my intuition of "this is actually complicated, and not just "forgot something complicated" was founded.  thanks for the links!You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Mismatch != impossibility. Read some Fowler.

Answer (score 0):

You should use table inheritance if your domain model uses inheritance.

The simplest, fastest method is Single Table Inheritance, and it is what Martin Fowler recommends. Yes, you end up with null fields. If they are at the "end" of your table, then modern databases are great at compacting them.

The more correct way is Class Table Inheritance, which solves your null "problem" but is much more complicated, and slower.

Either way, for a correct and flexible solution, you really need table inheritance. For example, if your Order Line Item can be for a Service or Product, table inheritance really helps here.

Comment: In SQLite, all values in all rows need one byte each to store the type, but for `NULL` values, that's it.